NavigationLink does not work when running the app on iOS 18
I am testing out my app on iOS 18 Developer Beta and I noticed that one of my NavigationLink components is not working. It works on all other previous iOS versions, so it's definitely an 18 specific issue.
I also have many other NavigationLink components in the app, which are working perfectly fine even on iOS 18, which leads me to believe that there is something wrong with this specific View Hierarchy.
Here's the SwiftUI struct containing the NavigationLink
struct TimelineScrollableListView: View {
@ObservedObject var viewModel: TimelineViewModel
var type: TimelineType
var body: some View {
    ScrollViewReader { proxy in
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(viewModel.timelineRows) { timelineRow in
                    switch (timelineRow) {
                    case .Data(let calculation):
                        let isSameDateAsToday = timelineRow.isSameDay(as: viewModel.dateToday)
                        let contentView = ContentView(
                            type: type,
                            calculations: calculation,
                            showBalanceForToday: viewModel.showBalanceOnToday,
                            responseBalanceType: viewModel.responseBalanceType
                        )
                        let timelineRowView = TimelineRowView(
                            date: calculation.date!,
                            isHighlighted: isSameDateAsToday,
                            contentView: contentView,
                            showRightArrow: viewModel.canNavigateToHistory
                        )
                            .id(isSameDateAsToday ? "today" : timelineRow.id)
                        if viewModel.canNavigateToHistory {
                            NavigationLink {
                                HistoryViewController.SwiftUI(date: calculation.date!)
                            } label: {
                                timelineRowView
                            }
                        } else {
                            timelineRowView
                        }
                    case .Separator(let date):
                        TimelineMonthSeparatorView(text: date.formattedText(format: "MMM. yyyy"))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.adjustTodaysDateIfNeeded()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                proxy.scrollTo("today", anchor: .center)
            }
            TimelinesHostingViewController.ViewMediator.shared.onTodayButtonPressed = {
                withAnimation {
                    proxy.scrollTo("today", anchor: .center)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
The HistoryViewController that I am trying to navigate to is written in UIKit, that's why I have a static helper function, that's why you see me calling the .SwiftUI(date...).
Here's the struct I am talking about:
struct SwiftUI: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var date: DateInRegion
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        return HistoryViewController(date: date)
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
        
    }
}

And also here is the navigation stack of the app in the moment when I try to execute the NavigationLink code.

When I tap on the NavigationLink item, nothing happens. No animation, no feedback whatsoever, the app just ignores it.

for NavigationLink to work, you need a NavigationStack

That's weird, I have NavigationLink all over the app and I never use NavigationStack. Plus, this being only an iOS 18 issue and other links working correctly makes me believe that there should be another solution, right?

@workingdogsupportUkraine the other point I want to make is that NavigationStack is available with iOS16 while NavigationLink is available in prior versions to that.

There was a comment in the release notes of one of the Xcode bètas: Deprecated NavigationLinks links with an isActive argument that are wrapped with a get/set Binding derived from another Binding may not update the destination view if the derived binding updates too late. Workaround: Adopt the navigationDestination(item:destination:) modifier

As @workingdogsupportUkraine states the documentation clearly says : « People click or tap a navigation link to present a view inside a NavigationStack or NavigationSplitView ». You can also use a NavigationView if you need compatibility with iOS versions earlier than 16

iOS 18 Developer Beta is clearly mentioned as the iOS not working.
NavigationLink does not work without a NavigationStack/NavigationSplitView or
the deprecated NavigationView. Change your NavigationView to NavigationStack
if you are targeting iOS 18. See also the docs,  NavigationStack
